# Serial port. write not working c# compact framwrork 2.0

Tags: c#-2.0

I am trying to write command for a device which is connected to computer via RS232, but it seems its not successfully writting command, please help.

My code

```
char stx = (char)0x02;
char etx = (char)0x03;
char data = '2';
char lrc = CalculateLRC(data.ToString() + etx.ToString());
char[] outputBuffer = {stx, data, etx, lrc };
mySerialPort.Write(outputBuffer, 0, outputBuffer.Length);
```

method

```
public static char CalculateLRC(string toEncode)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toEncode);
            byte LRC = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                LRC ^= bytes[i];
            }
            return Convert.ToChar(LRC);
        }
```

Comment: The format i received from device manufacturer is: 

<STX>Command Code<ETX><LRC>
Content Length of all these is 1, so should i send char byte to serial port or need to convert to byte and then send. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Longitudinal redundancy check (LRC) is the exclusive-or (XOR) of all the data bytes NOT including the STX and ETX. In your code the line where you CalculateLRC includes ETX, which is wrong.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: CalculateLRC(data.ToString() + etx.ToString());
has to be replaced with 
CalculateLRC(data.ToString());